# How to detect SEXP type by using clang-tool

Tags: c++, r, clang, clang-ast-matchers

I want to detect "SEXP" return type function by using clang-tool , and print it .

My clang tool :

```cpp
//define vistor
class myVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<myVisitor>{
    private:
        ASTContext *ast_c ;
    public:
        explicit myVisitor(CompilerInstance *CI): ast_c(&(CI->getASTContext())){
            myrewrite.setSourceMgr(ast_c->getSourceManager(), ast_c->getLangOpts());
        }
        virtual bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *func){
            string funcType = func->getDeclaredReturnTypeSourceRange().getAsString();
            std::cerr<<"type is "<<funcType<<endl;
            return true;
        }
};

//define consumer
class myASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
    private:
        myVisitor *visitor; 
    public:
        explicit myASTConsumer(CompilerInstance *CI): visitor(new myVisitor(CI)) {}// initialize the visitor

        virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &Context) {
            visitor->TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
        }
};
//define frontend action
class FA : public ASTFrontendAction {
    public:
        FA() {}
        virtual std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI, StringRef file) {
            return  make_unique<myASTConsumer>(&CI);
        }
};
int main(int argc , const char **argv){
    auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    if (!ExpectedParser) {
        // Fail gracefully for unsupported options.
        llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
        return 1;
    }
    CommonOptionsParser& op = ExpectedParser.get();
    ClangTool Tool(op.getCompilations(),op.getSourcePathList());

    int result = Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<FA>().get());
    return result;
}
```

My test.cpp :

```cpp
SEXP test() { 
    int a=0;
    SEXP result;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        a++;
    }
    return result; 
}
```

The expected output is `type is SEXP`

But the result is `type is int` , with error message unknown type name 'SEXP'

How do I edit my tool to get the SEXP type of a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem is .

1. Need to add `#include<R.h> #include<Rinternal.h>` at the top of code
2. The headers of R are in `/usr/share/R/include`
   But the path of clang will find header in normal include path , so we need to copy them into `/usr/local/include/`